# How to normalize convolutional weights in pytorch?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a CNN in `pytorch` and I need to normalize the convolution weights (filters) with L2 norm in each iteration. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Basically, in my particular experiment I need to replace the filters with their normalized value in the model (during both training and test).

Comment: Do you want to use L2-regularization?

Comment: No, I do not want L2-regularization. I just want to normalize convolutional weights. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly. But if I were asked to normalize the weights of NN layer at each iteration, I would do something like as follows.

```
for ite in range(100): # training iteration

    # write your code to train your model
    # update the parameters using optimizer.step() and then normalize

    with torch.no_grad():
        model.conv.weight.div_(torch.norm(model.conv.weight, dim=2, keepdim=True)
```

Here, the `model.conv` refers to the Convolution layer of the model. **Please make sure,** you give the `dim` parameter in `torch.norm()` function appropriately. I just set it to 2 to give you an example.

For example, if you are using `Conv1d`, then the shape of the weight parameters would be `(out_channels, in_channels, kW)`, then you can set `dim=2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question with more details. I need the normalization during the training as I want the model to use them to update weights.